# Regex for extracting fields

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match

This is my dump

```
Ack_ONE............................FAILED
[58] 0
[59] 0
[5A] 0
[5B] 0
dropball.....................................PASSED
nfrock_port@0x44A40000: Error: TX 0x00A9EFB6    
MAKEPIE.....................................FAILED
```

I am trying to extract the following using match command. So that I can have tests (Ack_ONE,dropball, Makepie) as `match.groups()[0]` and the results (FAILED,PASSED,FAILED) in `match.groups()[1]`.

```
Ack_ONE FAILED
dropball PASSED
Makepie FAILED
```

I am using the following regex command

```
match = re.search( r'\s*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)............................(.*?)\n', line)
```

How can I remove/ignore the `.`(dots) using regex and improve the above?

Comment: `............................` you can replace this by `\.{5,}` or `\.{10.}`

Comment: Actually the number of dots varies for each test. So I want to write a regex that just ignores all the dots and just gives the test name and the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that dots means "any character", so your regex matches for example:

```
dropball....r34....(...dfsd.....6.....tyu....PASSED
```

You should escape the `.` if you want to match the literal dot.

So you can have:

```
match = re.search( r'\s*(\w+)\.{28}(.*?)\n', line)
```

- `\w` matches any word character
- `\.{28}` matches 28 dots (you can expand it to `{x,y}` to match between `x` and `y` dots, or if you don't care about how many dots can appear, you can simply use `\.+`). If you want to ignore the dots, use `\.*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\.{5,}(.*?)(?:\n|$)
```

You can use this with `re.findall` to get your results.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/35

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\s*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\.{5,}(.*?)(?:\n|$)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "Ack_ONE............................FAILED\n[58] 0\n[59] 0\n[5A] 0\n[5B] 0\ndropball.....................................PASSED\nnfrock_port@0x44A40000: Error: TX 0x00A9EFB6    \nMAKEPIE.....................................FAILED"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the problem.

```
import re

text = '''
Ack_ONE............................FAILED
[58] 0
[59] 0
[5A] 0
[5B] 0
dropball.....................................PASSED
nfrock_port@0x44A40000: Error: TX 0x00A9EFB6    
MAKEPIE.....................................FAILED
'''

data = text.split('\n')
for item in data:
    if '...' in item:
        print re.findall(r'[^.]+.', item)
```

It prints out:

```
['Ack_ONE.', 'FAILED']
['dropball.', 'PASSED']
['MAKEPIE.', 'FAILED']
```